# Excel 2010 VBA click cell trigger macro to show list of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, mouse-click

When clicking on cell say d2 I want to show the values from j2:j6 in e2:e6.
When clicking on cell d3 I want to show the values from k2:k6 in e2:e6, etc.
Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add this to the code module behind your sheet. If it's Sheet1, in VBA's Code Explorer, right click on Sheet1 and choose View Code, then add this to the module:

```
Option Explicit

Const DISPLAY_TARGET As String = "E2:E6"
Const D2_SOURCE As String = "J2:J6"
Const D3_SOURCE As String = "K2:K6"

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$D$2"
      Range(DISPLAY_TARGET).Value = Range(D2_SOURCE).Value

    Case "$D$3"
      Range(DISPLAY_TARGET).Value = Range(D3_SOURCE).Value

    Case Else
      'Range(DISPLAY_TARGET).ClearContents

  End Select

End Sub
```

I've given you the option, after the Case Else statement, to clear E2:E6 contents, if the user clicks on any other cell than D2 or D3.