# Excel VBA display different range of values when clicking a cell

Tags: vba, macros

I have a question, to which I somewhat found an answer here: [Excel 2010 VBA click cell trigger macro to show list of values](https://superuser.com/questions/1027308/excel-2010-vba-click-cell-trigger-macro-to-show-list-of-values)

First off, I'm a very basic user of VBA. I have a table of 2 columns and 21 rows, the range is A2:B22. This is the summary of another data set, so my objective is to show another range of cells on the D column when A2 is selected, but I want this gone when the user clicks away to another cell.

For example, if A2 is selected(clicked on), I want to display X, Y, Z, T values on cells D2:D6. Then if A3 is selected, I want to clear x, Y, Z, T and instead display K, L M, N on cells D2:D6.

The formula on the link above works for me except for the Clear Contents row. It does not clear the contents when I click away. Only the last set of values remain. As a work around, where D4_SOURCE is an empty range of cells, I tried to insert one more line like this:

Case "B2:Z99"
Range(DISPLAY_TARGET).Value = Range(D4_SOURCE).Value

But this didn't work for B2:Z99, only with $B$2.

I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to show the detail behind the summary when the user clicks on the item in column A?

Answer (score -1):

the complete data is on another sheet looking like this:

```
A  1
A  2
A  3
B  4
B  5
C  6
C  7
C  8
C  9
D 10
D 11
D 12
```

In this summary, I want to make it so that when the user clicks on "A", they will see 1, 2 and 3 values. Then when they click on "B" the previous data will be cleared and they will see 4, 5 instead.

I can also copy the complete data to the "Summary" sheet and just hide those columns, if it will make it easier for macro.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. You should edit your original question to add additional information if that's what you want to do.